# Pandas .to_csv not exporting correct output into the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to put a dataframe into a csv file and then access it. But by doing so the NaN values are showing up and the data are misaligned.

```
expenses = df.iloc[:][['Description','Debit']].dropna()
```

Here, i am trying to get the Description and debit column where there is no NaN data.

```
expenses.to_csv(path_or_buf= 'expenses.csv',index=False, header=["Description", "Debit"],encoding='utf-8')
expenses = pd.read_csv("expenses.csv", thousands=",", header= 0)
```

And then saving that dataframe into expenses and trying to access the same csv file but the content is misaligned. When I open the csv file its correct.

Here, is a screenshot to help you understand:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, by [default](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) the `inplace=False`, when you use dropna , do:

```
df.dropna(subset=['Description','Debit'], inplace=True)
```

It should work. Your `df`, in this case, should have dropped the `NaN` values on these two columns.

Comment: I tried the same but it is making "expenses" dataframe into NoneType. And unable to use the to_csv method further down the line.

Comment: this way, the original dataframe itself is changed, and you can do, df.to_csv() directly, if you could share some sample rows, I can give you the working example.